# comparing char off file descriptors c

Tags: c, linux, readfile

I need to compare 2 chars off file descriptors.

my file sample.txt includes "first"
my file sample2.txt includes "firbbbbbbst"

I need to return "not similar", but it always returns "similar" and never actually reads the lines to the buffer.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
ssize_t ret_in, ret_out;
char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
char buffer2[BUF_SIZE];
int where=0;    
int fileDes1;
int fileDes2;

      fileDes1 = open("home/aviad/Desktop/comparing/in1/sample.txt", O_RDONLY);
      fileDes2 = open("home/aviad/Desktop/comparing/in2/sample2.txt", O_RDONLY);
      while((ret_in = fread (buffer, BUF_SIZE, 1, fileDes1)) > 0)
      {
          ret_out= fread (buffer, BUF_SIZE, 1, fileDes2);

          if (buffer[where] == buffer2[where])
          {
              printf("%c", buffer[where]);
              where++;
          }
          else {
              printf("nor similar\n");
              break;
          }
      }
      printf("similar\n");
      printf("%c", buffer[2]);   //garbage
      printf("%c", buffer2[2]);  //garbage
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not use *strncmp* ? http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp

Comment: this is not the problem, problem is that data never gets in buffer

Comment: Drop the `&` operator when passing `buffer` and `buffer2` to `fread`.

Comment: Also, take a hard look at the structure of your loop; you read in your buffers, compare the first character in each, then read the buffers again, compare the second character in each, etc.

Comment: @john Bode this is exactly what I wish to do. I have just updated , could you take a look ? it still does not work

Comment: `ret_out= fread (buffer, BUF_SIZE, 1, fileDes2);` maybe this should be buffer2?

Comment: And check the return vale of the open function!

Comment: This never reads into buffer2. Also you're reading in 1 item of size BUF_SIZE. fread returns the number of **items** read, which will be zero if file size is smaller than BUF_SIZE. Try swapping 1 & BUF_SIZE.

Comment: thank youall.
problem was "/home.." instead of "home.." in file dest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need this:

Disclaimer: untested code that may not work or even compile, but it should at least give you an idea. Anyway there is still room for improvement.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
ssize_t ret_in, ret_out;
char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
char buffer2[BUF_SIZE];
int where=0;    
int fileDes1;
int fileDes2;
int notsimilar = 0;
int i = 0;

      fileDes1 = open("home/aviad/Desktop/comparing/in1/sample.txt", O_RDONLY);
      fileDes2 = open("home/aviad/Desktop/comparing/in2/sample2.txt", O_RDONLY);

      while((ret_in = fread (buffer, BUF_SIZE, 1, fileDes1)) > 0)
      {
        ret_out= fread (buffer, BUF_SIZE, 1, fileDes2);

        if (ret_out != ret_in)  // file sizes different -> not similar
        {
          notsimilar = 1;
          break;
        }
        else
        {
          for (i = 0; i < ret_out)
          {
            if (buffer[i] == buffer2[i])
            {
                printf("%c", buffer[i]);
                where++;
            }
            else
            {
                notsimilar = 1;
            }
          }
        }
      }

      if (notsimilar)
        printf("similar\n");
      else
        printf("similar\n");

      printf("%c", buffer[i]);
      printf("%c", buffer2[i]);
      return 0;
}
```

You also should test if the files could actually be opened. You just assume both files exist.